# Apple Watch App Freezing overnight - How can you debug it?

Tags: ios, swift2, apple-watch

I created a app and it works great.  The odd thing is after I had the watch charge overnight when I switch to the app it switches OK but the app is non-responsive or responds to navigation after long delays.

The best I could tell from the log on the device is that the app comes to the foreground but does not respond to navigation commands and it appears to go into the background, but maybe that is normal scheduling ?

```
    ... 
    Dec  9 11:10:10 Jims-AppleWatch iap2d[213] <Warning>: process com.ijaz.iInteract.watchkitapp.watchkitextension is now running the foreground
    Dec  9 11:10:11 Jims-AppleWatch iap2d[213] <Warning>: process com.ijaz.iInteract.watchkitapp is now suspending
 ...
```

After killing the application, and relaunching it the behavior is more of what I expect, once I launch it it does not suspend:

```
Dec  9 11:10:18 Jims-AppleWatch iap2d[213] <Warning>: process com.ijaz.iInteract.watchkitapp is now running the foreground
Dec  9 11:10:18 Jims-AppleWatch iap2d[213] <Warning>: process com.ijaz.iInteract.watchkitapp.watchkitextension is now running the foreground
Dec  9 11:10:26 Jims-AppleWatch Carousel[96] <Notice>: (Note ) log.facility.voicetrigger: ::: Received request to DISABLE voice trigger - Reason: Backlight turned on)
Dec  9 11:10:31 Jims-AppleWatch sharingd[26] <Error>: 11:10:31.383 : Failed to get taskInfo for Task <com.apple.nanoweatherd|B7795F05-2BDE-4896-9428-59A9442918BF>.<1>, replyMessage (null)
Dec  9 11:10:42 Jims-AppleWatch timed[33] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 12/09/2015 19:10:41±0.01 from "TMLSSourceComputed"
Dec  9 11:10:42 Jims-AppleWatch timed[33] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 139.59min. Need active time in 217.71min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
Dec  9 11:10:42 Jims-AppleWatch UserEventAgent[22] <Error>: validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (471381042.7) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Dec  9 11:10:42 Jims-AppleWatch timed[33] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Received time 12/09/2015 19:10:42±0.00 from "TMLSSourceDevice"
Dec  9 11:10:42 Jims-AppleWatch timed[33] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 139.58min. Need active time in 217.71min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
Dec  9 11:10:42 Jims-AppleWatch UserEventAgent[22] <Error>: validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (471381042.9) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Dec  9 11:10:43 Jims-AppleWatch timed[33] <Notice>: (Error) CoreTime: Error requesting proactive time check job
```

I will try and reproduce today/tonight but I need strategy to debug it if/when i do.

Here are the controllers involved:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView:WKInterfaceTable!
    var panels:[Panel] = [Panel]()

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        panels = Panel.readFromPlist()
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()
        setupTable()
    }

    private func setupTable() {

        var rowTypesList = [String]()

        for _ in panels {
            rowTypesList.append("PanelRow")
        }

        tableView.setRowTypes(rowTypesList)

        for var i = 0; i < tableView.numberOfRows; i++ {

            let panelRow = tableView.rowControllerAtIndex(i) as! PanelRow
            let panel = panels[i]
            panelRow.button.setTitle(panel.title)
            panelRow.button.setBackgroundColor(panel.color)
        }

    }

    override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject? {
        return panels[rowIndex]
    }


}
class PanelController: WKInterfaceController {

    //Mark : Properties
    @IBOutlet var PanelVerticalGroup: WKInterfaceGroup!
    @IBOutlet var PanelTitle: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var Button1: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button2: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button3: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet var Button4: WKInterfaceButton!


    var panel : Panel?

    //Mark :  Functions
    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        let buttons = [self.Button1,self.Button2,self.Button3,self.Button4]

        for button in buttons {
            button.setHidden(true)
        }

        // Configure interface objects here.
        self.panel = context as? Panel
        PanelVerticalGroup.setBackgroundColor(panel!.color)
        PanelTitle.setText(panel!.title + " ...")
        PanelTitle.setTextColor(UIColor.blackColor())

        var i = 0
        for interaction in panel!.interactions {
            let button = buttons[i++]
            button.setHidden(false)
            button.setBackgroundImage(interaction.picture)
        }

    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }


    override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {
        let index = Int(segueIdentifier)

        //return the interaction object so we can draw the button etc
        let interaction = panel!.interactions[index!]
        let color = panel!.color
        let params : [AnyObject]? = [interaction,color]
        return params
    }

}
```